# Express router not awaiting the forEach loop

Tags: node.js, express

Express router is not awaiting my `forEach` loop and sends the old unmanipulated object as a response instead of the new manipulated data.

Here I am using Sequalize as my ORM.

```
router.get('/', async (req,res) => {
    try {
        let trainings = await db.Training.findAll();
        let locations = await db.Location.findAll();

        await locations.forEach(location => {
            trainings.forEach(training => {
                if(location.trainingId == training.id){
                    training["location"] = location
                }
            })
        })

        res.status(200).json({
            training:trainings
        })
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(404).json({
            message : err
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: I tried all the possible scenarios, it would be great if I get an answer with an example. That is if you can edit my code and show it to me it would be great.

Comment: Why are you awaiting that `forEach`? There's no Promise inside it

Comment: It does not seem to work either way.

Comment: The issue must be due to something else. If you log `location.trainingId == training.id` what do you get?

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return a promise (it doesn't return anything!) so it can't be awaited. If you need to async work in sequence use a `for` or `for-of` loop. If you need to do async work in parallel, use `Promise.all`.

Comment: Everything works in console.log() but the response I get in postman is the origin unmanipulated object.

Comment: You need to catch all the promises and send the response after calling Promise.all(promises)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are using the `await` keyword against a synchronous process which is

```
locations.forEach(location => {
        trainings.forEach(training => {
            if(location.trainingId == training.id){
                training["location"] = location
            }
        })
    })
```

These lines of code doesn't return any promise or behave like a promise. So one solution can be having a function

```
function modify(trainings,locations){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        locations.forEach(location => {
        trainings.forEach(training => {
            if(location.trainingId == training.id){
                training["location"] = location
            }
        })
        })
        resolve('done')
    })
}
```

then have it like this

```
let trainings = await db.Training.findAll();
let locations = await db.Location.findAll();
await modify(trainings,locations)
```

or you can simply remove the `await` keyword from your current state of code.

Comment: This does not work, 
Everything works in console.log() but the response I get in postman is the origin unmanipulated object.

Comment: Did you `console.log()` before the `res.send()` line ?